# Checking If Values in Array Are Different Java

Tags: java

I've got this code:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(LargeInt passedIn)//
{
  if(passedIn == null)
  {   
     throw new RuntimeException("NullExceptionError");
  }   
  int ewu = 0;
  int avs = 0;

  if(this.myArray.length != passedIn.myArray.length)
  {   
     return this.myArray.length - passedIn.myArray.length;
  }
  for(this.myArray.length == passedIn.myArray.length)
  {



  }
  for(int x = 0; x < this.myArray.length; x++)
  {
     ewu += this.myArray[x];       
  }
  for(int x = 0; x < passedIn.myArray.length; x++)
  {
     avs += passedIn.myArray[x];
  }
  return ewu - avs;
```

}

My goal is, under this line:

```
for(this.myArray.length == passedIn.myArray.length)
```

I want to If the lengths are equal, go through the array until a value that is different is found. Then subtract those two values and return. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: What is the purpose of this `if(passedIn == null) { throw new RuntimeException("NullExceptionError"); }`? If you check for `null` just to throw an Exception, then just remove that check. You'll get your desired `NullPointerException` if the variable is `null` "automatically".

Comment: Explain your `for(this.myArray.length == passedIn.myArray.length)` loop.

Comment: You already know how to use a `for` so just use another one and use `if (myArray[x] != passedIn.myArray[x]) { }` inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
public int compareTo(LargeInt passedIn)
{
    if (this.myArray.length != passedIn.myArray.length)
    {
        return this.myArray.length - passedIn.myArray.length;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < this.myArray.length; i++) {
        if (this.myArray[i] != passedIn.myArray[i])
            return this.myArray[i] - passedIn.myArray[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the arrays are different lengths you've returned already. There is no point in checking whether they are the same length.
And after you've checked for differences in the new loop, you can be sure that they are identical and skip those loops that sum up the arrays. They will have the same sum since they must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

> If the lengths are equal

so, why not use `if(myArray.length == passedIn.myArray.length)` instead of that (syntactically incorrect) `for`-loop? (In your case, it is just the `else`of the condition before).

If the condition is `true`, iterate over the arrays as you did by the loops below.